# How to exclude ajax from htaccess?

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to force trailling slash in my site. I have found the bellow code that it works but it causes problem with ajax code.

This is my htaccess code

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

So now I want to exclude the ajax from this or I if we can exclude a specific url that uses ajax.

e.g. `my-site.com/onepage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exclude `/onepage` you can use a negitive `RewriteCond` :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/onepage
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```